# creating new environment in specified directory

Tags: bash, datascience-anaconda

my current situation is that I am trying to create a conda environment for some bioinformatics work in a shared server.  My assigned home directory with my account only has storage for 10G and I need slightly more.  I have a scratch directory with infinite storage and I am wondering if there is a way I can establish a environment and install the needed programs in that environment in the scratch folder? can I just move the /.conda/ folder from my home to this scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving it to the scratch directory and replace it by a symlink. Like so:

```
mv ~/.conda /scratch/conda
ln -s /scratch/conda ~/.conda
```

Keep in mind that you might lose your data in case the sysadmin wipes the scratch directory.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  One thing I noticed is the reappearance of .conda/ in my home directory, is this a product of the symlink?

Comment: This _is_ the symbolic link pointing to `/scratch/conda`. `ls -l` will show you where it points.